# How to deploy multiple processes(bundles) in 1 jar onto OSGI felix

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, osgi-bundle

I'm quite new to OSGI framework so I do not how to deploy multiple processes(bundles) in 1 jar onto it. Particularly, I have installed the Apache Felix With Web Console following this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KqhpgiFNQso). I have also tried to deploy my jar file and started it as the bundle. The jar's purpose is like a job to process some activities.

However, I would like to have multiple jobs in just 1 jar file so that when I deploy that jar on Felix the framework can identifies and presents them as individual parts.

For example, I want to have 3 jobs(A,B,C) in my jar and when I deploy that jar onto Felix, maybe the Web Console still define the jar as 1 bundle but it could present both job A, job B and Job C and I can do some bundle function on them like update/start/stop/...

Comment: are your jobs 1-time jobs or a long running server process?

Comment: They would be short-lived jobs which scheduled to process a finite set of data at particular time and then stop to wait for the next execution time.